# How to create a folder in site->default->files with write read permissions with Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on Ubuntu and I need to create a folder in Drupal's default->files folder with write permission so that I would be able to add files to that folder later on.

Here is the code I have:

```
drupal_mkdir('public://' . $new_dir . '/');
$file = file_copy($file, 'public://' . $new_dir . '/' . $file_name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    drupal_mkdir('public://' . $new_dir , 0777);
```

if you need it to be recursive set third argument to true.

update:

```
    $oldumask = umask(0);
    drupal_mkdir("public://". $new_dir , 0777);
    umask($oldumask);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply bhab, I tried it this way too but did't work

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error? Is your files folder writable?

Comment: Do not give any error but none of files copy to the folder. Once I changed the permission by hand through CLI it works

Comment: I have updated my answer and is working for me. Hope works for u too.

Answer (score 0):

fire this command and than try your code ..
chmod -R 0700 sites/default/files